# Tomcat Javamail Port 365?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, jakarta-mail

I have followed an example where I add a resource to my webapp context.xml

```
<Resource auth="Container" mail.smtp.host="localhost" 
    name="containeremail" type="javax.mail.Session" />
```

And in the web.xml I have :

```
<resource-ref>
<description>Container Email resource</description>
<res-ref-name>containeremail</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.mail.Session</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
<res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
```

I then use the Javamail to send emails like this :

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");            
mailSession=(Session)envCtx.lookup("containeremail");                                             
mailSession.setDebug(true);


Transport.send(message);
```

This works well in my dev environment.

However when I deploy in in my production CENTOS box I get this exception :

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 365;
```

nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Postfix is installed and running on both machines. I even tried specifying the port to 25 in the context.xml :

```
mail.smtp.port="25"
```

But even with this it still has the exception above referring to port 365 ????

Any ideas on what is wrong ?

Thanks

Spunog

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Tomcat is creating the javax.mail.Session instance in this case, but if it's using Session.getDefaultInstance instead of Session.getInstance you could be getting a Session with someone else's configuration, which is why it's using port 365.

You could always bypass Tomcat's resource configuration and call Session.getInstance yourself.

Comment: Well there is no Session.getInstance called in this case you get the session from the context.

Comment: Also the same version of tomcat is automatically using port 25 on my ubuntu dev machine.

Comment: Right, my question was about how Tomcat implements getting the Session from the context.  I understand that you're not calling it explicitly.  There are only two ways to create a Session object so one way or another Tomcat must be using one of them but it's not clear which one Tomcat is using internally.